# Advanced software to organize and manage a life of photos

Tags: metadata

I'm looking for a program that would allow me to get control over my large (hundreds of GB) collection of photos. There are several photo viewers and collection managers (e.g. Shotwell), but those that I've tried seem to lack the features I'd like. I'm looking for:

- Support for finding and deleting duplicates, preferrably showing me both pictures for comparison and telling me where they are, so I can decide which to delete.
- Help with organizing the pictures. Metadata in all its glory, but the best I've had in this regard was Picasa, the face recognition feature being a huge plus. But then it got shut down.
- Powerful GUI. I'll probably have a lot of pics to go through if I find a software solution, since in many cases the metadata/folders structure is lacking. The more click I can save, the better. Batch processing/deleting/tagging very much appreciated. "easy to use" is not the most important thing, as long as I can get a lot of stuff done.

Additionally, I'm primarily on linux so it would be a huge bonus if it was available there, but if not, I'd love to hear about options for other OSes, so I have stuff to compare with.

Comment: you can still use an older version of picasa on linux, if you search for a download link

Answer (score 0):

[Tonfotos](https://tonfotos.com/) seem to be perfect fit for your criteria:

- Has quite original implementation of [duplicate photos deletion](https://tonfotos.com/articles/delete_duplicates/), that can save a lot of time in certain cases
- Has face recognition feature
- Supports Linux

I use it with my photo and video collection that is just a little bit bellow 1Tb. I am not that sure about "powerful GUI", as this one tends to look pretty simple.